# Add Consumers without adding MassTransit to a dependency injection container

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, azureservicebus, masstransit

I am trying to do an implementation of MassTransit that is agnostic to the type of transport (i.e. Azure Service Bus, RabbitMQ, etc.). I have decoupled the logic from the DI container in that the DI container adds the scope for the interface to concrete class and has a factory to determine the transport based upon a configuration. This works for publish and send but when I attempt to do a request/response or a consume, the exchanges/queues for RabbitMq and the topics and queue for Azure service bus are created but no message is received.

My thought is that I can then take the class library that is doing all of the logic and port from project to project without having a large snippet of all of the consumers since those may differ from project to project.

I feel as though I am missing something important. This will not work without doing an .AddConsumer into a DI container after using AddMassTransit to add the bus configuration into the DI container which is the opposite of what I am trying.

I built an integration test project to attempt TDD while ironing out this functionality before adding to the service and got blocked here. The response variable never returns and I get a timeout eventually. The integration project only depends on the MassTransit class library and a Configuration class library and is actually speaking directly to the transport (as opposed to mocking it).

Am I close or do I need to abandon this quest?

Code-wise from my current project:

**Startup.cs**

```
        Configuration.IConfigurationProvider cfg = new ServiceFabricConfigurationProvider();
        switch (cfg.MessageService.MessagingService)
        {
            case "AzureServiceBus":
                services.AddScoped<IMassTransitTransport, MassTransitAzureServiceBusTransport>();
                break;
            case "RabbitMq":
                services.AddScoped<IMassTransitTransport, MassTransitRabbitMqTransport>();
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid message service");
        };

        services.AddScoped<IMessagingService, MassTransitMessagingService>();
```

Transport classes are very similar as they have a common interface - showing both below

**IMassTransitTransport**

```
public interface IMassTransitTransport
{
    IBusControl BusControl { get; }
}
```

**MassTransitAzureServiceBusTransport**

```
public sealed class MassTransitAzureServiceBusTransport : IMassTransitTransport
{
    readonly IConfigurationProvider configProvider;

    public MassTransitAzureServiceBusTransport(IConfigurationProvider configProvider)
    {
        this.configProvider = configProvider;
        BusControl = ConfigureBus();
        BusControl.StartAsync();
    }

    public IBusControl BusControl { get; }

    IBusControl ConfigureBus()
    {
        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg => 
        {
            cfg.Host(configProvider.AzureServiceBus.AzureServiceBusConnectionString);

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("MyQueue", e => 
            {
                e.Consumer<ConsumerClass>();
            });
        });
    }
```

**MassTransitRabbitMqTransport**

```
public sealed class MassTransitRabbitMqTransport : IMassTransitTransport
{
    readonly IConfigurationProvider configProvider;

    public MassTransitRabbitMqTransport(IConfigurationProvider configProvider)
    {
        this.configProvider = configProvider;
        BusControl = ConfigureBus();
        BusControl.StartAsync();
    }

    public IBusControl BusControl { get; }

    IBusControl ConfigureBus()
    {
        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {

            cfg.Host(new Uri(configProvider.Rabbit.HostAddress), host =>
            {
                host.Username(configProvider.Rabbit.Username);
                host.Password(configProvider.Rabbit.Password);
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("MyQueue", e => 
            {
                e.Consumer<ConsumerClass>();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**Messaging Service**

```
public interface IMessagingService
{
    Task Publish<T>(object payload) where T : class;
    Task Send<T>(object payload) where T : class;
}

public class MassTransitMessagingService : IMessagingService
{
    readonly IMassTransitTransport massTransitTransport;

    public MassTransitMessagingService(IMassTransitTransport massTransitTransport)
    {
        //transport bus config already happens in massTransitTransport constructor
        this.massTransitTransport = massTransitTransport;
    }

    public async Task Publish<T>(object payload) where T : class
    {
        await massTransitTransport.BusControl.Publish<T>(payload);
    }

    public async Task Send<T>(object payload) where T : class
    {
        var endpoint = await massTransitTransport.BusControl.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri(massTransitTransport.BusControl.Address, typeof(T).ToString()));
        await endpoint.Send<T>(payload);
    }
}
```

**Request / Response Interfaces and classes**

```
public interface IEventRequest
{
    Guid EventGuid { get; set; }
    string Message { get; set; }
}

public interface IEventResponse
{
    Guid EventGuid { get; set; }
    string RequestMessage { get; set; }
    string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
}

public class ConsumerClass : IConsumer<IEventResponse>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IEventResponse> context)
    {
        var payloadResponse = new
        {
            context.Message.EventGuid,
            context.Message.RequestMessage,
            ResponseMessage = "This is the response message;"
        };

        await context.RespondAsync(payloadResponse);
    }
}
```

**Test method to perform a request/response**

```
    [Test]
    public async Task SendAndReceiveMessage()
    {
        // arrange
        var config = GetConfiguration();
        var transport = new MassTransitRabbitMqTransport(config);

        var payload = new
        {
            EventGuid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Message = "This is an event message"
        };

        var clientFactory = transport.BusControl.CreateClientFactory();
        var client = clientFactory.CreateRequestClient<IEventRequest>();
        var response = await client.GetResponse<ConsumerClass>(payload);

    }
```

**Update 1**

I have made the following modifications as a result of the feedback from Chris Patterson. I believe I caused confusion by showing the fragment from the startup class.

There are really 2 things going on here: an API project that contains the pieces above and the refactored code fragments below and an integration test project.

In terms of the integration test project, there are really only 3 class libraries used. The integration test project does not contain a DI container since it is a test project and I want to see if it is possible to decouple the logic from the DI container. Also, I do not have ILogger present within the integration test project.

The entire solution is an API project that does have a startup with the built in DI container and a controller that implements a publish. My attempt is to decouple the MassTransit logic from the DI container so that the MassTransitTransport project may be used elsewhere and so any transport supported by MassTransit can be used. My question(s) are if this is a bad idea in terms of consuming the message (i.e. cannot be done unless using a DI container) or if it can be done. If it can be done, what am I missing/what do I have wrong?

Configuration 
 - to utilize IConfigurationProvider
MassTransitTransport 
 - contains ConsumerClass, IEventRequest, IEventResponse, EventResponse,
   IMassTransitTransport, MassTransitTransportRabbitMqTransport,
   MassTransitZaureServiceBusTransport, IMessagingService,
   MassTransitMessagingService
MassTransitTransport.Integration
 - contains MassTransitMessagingServiceTests,
   NonServiceFabricConfigurationProvider

*Created EventResponse and use it in the ConsumerClass*

```
public class EventResponse : IEventResponse
{
    public Guid EventGuid { get; set; }
    public string RequestMessage { get; set; }
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
}
```

*Consumer Class*

```
public class ConsumerClass : IConsumer<IEventResponse>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IEventResponse> context)
    {
        var payloadResponse = new EventResponse()
        {
            EventGuid = context.Message.EventGuid,
            RequestMessage = context.Message.RequestMessage,
            ResponseMessage = "This is the response message;"
        };

        await context.RespondAsync(payloadResponse);
    }
}
```

*Integration Test Project*

```
    [Test]
    public async Task SendAndReceiveMessage()
    {
        // arrange
        var config = GetConfiguration();
        var transport = new MassTransitRabbitMqTransport(config);
        //var transport = new MassTransitAzureServiceBusTransport(config);

        var payload = new
        {
            EventGuid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Message = "This is an event message"
        };

        var clientFactory = transport.BusControl.CreateClientFactory();
        var client = clientFactory.CreateRequestClient<IEventRequest>();
        var response = await client.GetResponse<IEventResponse>(payload);
    }
```

*Error Message Received*

MassTransit.RequestTimeoutException : Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: 7a000000-9a3c-0005-8037-08d80882f498

Comment: Your `payloadResponse` is an anonymous type, which isn't allowed. Enabling logging (via ILoggerFactory, see the docs) would have shown you the error. You need to use ResponseAsync<T>().

Comment: Also, `GetResponse<IEventResponse>()` - the consumer isn't the message type for the response.

Comment: In addition, I would avoid starting the bus, or doing any IO in general in the service configuration. The `ConfigureServices` method is to _configure_ things, not to start the infrastructure. You could register the hosted service to start and stop the bus `services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(new BusHostedService(bus))`

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I have done some refactoring but am still getting timeouts. I added an Update 1 to attempt to clarify my question since I was misleading. I am attempting to decouple the MassTransit project from the DI container as much as possible since my plan is for that component to be plugged into other solutions. Please let me know if this is not a good idea (i.e. MassTransit depends on the DI container?)

Comment: MassTransit doesn't require DI at all.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I am confused then. With the integration test project that I created, I never get past the line: var response = await client.GetResponse<IEventResponse>(payload); I thought that it would call the ConsumerClass but it does not. Is there a setup I am missing?

Comment: You're calling StartAsync() in the constructor, and not awaiting it. Usually when a response times out, it's because the bus isn't started.

Comment: I would suggest using the test harness for unit testing, as described in the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/testing.html). You are dragging way too many unrelated concerns into your tests. And adding a ton of complexity around yourself by trying to be agnostic - perhaps consider where you draw the lines between the business logic that is only dependent upon MassTransit, and then have separate assemblies for your transport integrations.

Comment: Thanks Chris - there were 2 issues. The first was StartAsync instead of Start. The 2nd was that the ConsumerClass was not implemented correctly. It should have inherited from IConsumer<IEventRequest> and had the method as public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IEventRequest> context). After that, everything worked. I do think that going the DI path will be cleaner though and will probably be going that direction. Thank you for all of your assistance - it was greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding the answer in the comment to close this issue:

there were 2 issues. The first was StartAsync instead of Start. The 2nd was that the ConsumerClass was not implemented correctly. It should have inherited from IConsumer and had the method as public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext context). After that, everything worked.